# Как в ВК api нажать на одну из кнопок данной клавиатуры программно?

Tags: python, вконтакте, клавиатура

Как с помощью **python** зафиксировать **event** клавиатуры от условного сообщества и отправить нажатие на одну из кнопок клавиатуры?
Мне нужно именно **отправить нажатие** на кнопку, ибо отправить просто текст кнопки **не решает проблему**.

Comment: Какими инструментами Вы решаете задачу? У Вас есть ключ `API` с необходимыми правами?

Comment: Да. У меня есть token в котором все права на мою страницу.
Я не новичок, но ранее не решал подобную задачу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `API` ВКонтакте нет понятия "нажатие на кнопку", как и событий клавиатуры. Вся функциональность клавиатур [реализуется](https://vk.com/dev/bots_docs_3?f=4.3.%2BSending%2Bthe%2Bkeyboard) непосредственно через сообщения (поэтому, кстати, нельзя воспользоваться клавиатурой без отправки сообщения).

Если более конкретно — то всё реализуется через метод [`messages.send`](https://vk.com/dev/messages.send). Клавиатура [прикладывается](https://vk.com/dev/bots_docs_3?f=4.2.%20Data%20structure) к нему в виде объекта JSON.

Когда пользователь нажимает одну из кнопок клавиатуры, отправляется сообщение с текстом из параметра `label`. Если установлен параметр `payload`, он также прикрепляется к сообщению.

На сервере есть только 2 способа узнать о нажатии кнопки — проверить либо `text`, либо `payload`. Если Вы говорите, что отправка текста не решает проблему, то Вам нужно приложить к сообщению `payload`. Узнать его можете из сообщения, к которому прикладывалась клавиатура